# Conflict with props

Tags: reactjs, redux

What will happen if we pass a prop when calling a component and also with the map state to props

```
<Modal foo={1} ... />

const Modal = ({ foo, ... }) => {
     console.log(foo) // 1 or 2 ? and Why ? is it random ?
}

export default connect(
    (state) => ({
        foo: state.foo, // let's say the value in the reducer is 2
        ...
    })
)(Modal)
```

is there a rule or it's random ?

Comment: You can see the logic in https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/mergeProps.js. It's mentioned that they get merged in [the connect docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#connect-extracting-data-with-mapstatetoprops).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

connect is a HOC which passes the values received from `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` to the component.

The values passed from `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` will override the props passed on to the component.

So in the above case `console.log({foo})` will log `2`.

---

To understand it better you may think of `Component` being used in `connect like`

```
<Component {...ownProps} {...valuesFromConnectArgs} />
```

---

You may also look at [connect code from react redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/mergeProps.js) which has the following method to mergeProps

```
export function defaultMergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) {
  return { ...ownProps, ...stateProps, ...dispatchProps }
}
```

You may look at the [demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/v8lvqvo437)

Comment: Thank @ShubhamKhatri, so it's because the order we have here `{ ...ownProps, ...stateProps, ...dispatchProps }` ? if we spread `ownProps` at last then it will override `stateProps` ?

Comment: @Youssef,yes you are right,you can do so in mapStateToProps